# Search for small, unknown, relevant websites

Tags: search

How can you search the internet for small, undiscovered, or unpopular websites that are relevant to your search query?

Google search results are flooded with major providers (not to mention bias) and I want to avoid results from YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, Amazon, Pintretest, CNN, NBA, etc.

In the past, I've tried simply appending a list of excluded websites to my search queries, but this is cumbersome and often insufficient to find unpopular pages.

A possible workaround, though not a good solution since relevance degrades, might be to visit links many pages down a Google search result. If I try to manually check many pages deep, I quickly hit a limit, and it still only shows popular sites.

For instance, if I type "*test*" into Google it claims to have found 3,260,000,000 results, but on the 32nd page it ends, showing no more results, and the search results occupying this final page are still just the popular sites: CNN, Gizmodo, National Post, MSN, etc. Showing omitted repeated results does not help.

*Millionshort.com claims to show deep results from Google, but after I tested it, I think it fails utterly.

I've also tried DuckDuckGo, but its results are an even more restricted set than a Google search, and doesn't serve up anything really new.

Searching unpopular sites would yield many benefits such as potentially locating new upstart websites, increasing your search breadth for completeness, finding an unpopular opinion, or locating a small site that sells homemade products from their own websites, this negating the need for a middleman like eBay or Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Google Search hasn't a search operator or tool to make it easier to find "unpopular" sites. To learn about the supported search operators see [Refine web searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433)

It looks to me that your cumberstone solution is the only available by using Google, but there are some tools that could help. Just to mention one, if you use Chrome, you could try [Personal Blocklist (By Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) or another similar Chrome extension.

Comment: Which documentation? The question was not intended to be Google specific. Google is mentioned to clarify the broader web-search issue. However, the page blocker extension is a good idea

Comment: @CalebDevine I added a link to the help page about supported search operators.

Comment: Regarding the broader web-search issue perhaps you would like to edit your question to make it clear but bear in mind that making a question that encompases several web applications could make it too broad for this site.

Comment: If this is just about search in general, then the question is too broad.

Comment: @CalebDevine ^^^

Answer (score 1):

From a quick test on some popular search engines, each engine has a limit of how many results it will give you:

- [Google](https://www.google.com) - 42
- [Bing](https://www.bing.com/) - 100 - **Winner**
- [Yahoo](https://search.yahoo.com/) - 88
- [Yandex](https://yandex.com/) - 65

So the best shot<sup>(1)</sup> for you is to **go with [Bing](https://www.bing.com/) and filter some popular websites you don't want - and then jump to the end of the results.**

On Bing, to jump directly to the 100 page, change the URL parameters `first` to be `991`, for example, this is the 100'th page of the results for `test`:

- Maybe some of the parameters cam be omitted, but those are the parameters Bing adds.

[https://www.bing.com/search?q=test&go=Submit&qs=ds&**first=991**&FORM=PERE4](https://www.bing.com/search?q=test&go=Submit&qs=ds&first=991&FORM=PERE4)

<sup>(1)</sup> Not including using custom extensions to manipulate search results, as Ruben suggested.